# Show that every finite subset of $\{0,1\}^*$ is recursive

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

How can I show that every finite subset of $\{0,1\}^*$ is recursive ?

Comment: Given a finite subset of $\{0,1\}^*$, show how to write a Turing machine that only accepts exactly that set. It's not hard.

Comment: Induct on the size of the subset

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I need to show that every finite subset is recursive not just a one subset.

Comment: @Amr I don't know induction. It is an assignment question and we didn't cover induction.

Comment: And I asked, given a finite subset, how would you write a Turing machine. You don't need a single Turing machine, just one for every finite subset.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So I would just say we could design a TM M that keep reading 0s and 1s while advancing to the right of the tape until it hits a blank (end of tape) and enter the accepting state. Is that enough justification ?

Comment: Right. Your turing machine is just (mostly) a binary tree. It has a finite number of nodes because the set it finite, so there is a maximum length for the tree.

Comment: A little more re what @ThomasAndrews said: The tree is all the strings in the finite set + their prefixes. The TM has a state for every node in the binary tree. The accepting states   correspond to the leaves of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every finite subset of $\left \{ 0,1 \right \}^*$ like $L$ is a regular language. It is easy to construct a DFA $M$ such that $L(M)=L$. Now Let $M'$ be a turing machine such that works like $M$ and in every transition head goes right on tape.

Comment: Presumably, you forgot the $*$ in $\{0,1\}^*$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thank you for your comment. I edited my post.